# Batch calls with Facebook Graph API & PHP

Tags: php, batch-file, facebook-graph-api

Designing my first app against the Graph API, using version 2.1.2 of the Facebook supplied PHP library.  Trying to maximize performance, etc out of the box and want to batch a few calls together into one call, but can't find anything in the documentation...  I am sure I must be missing something simple, but am stumped.

I'd like to turn these calls (just an example) into a single batched call:

```
$me     = $facebook->api('/me', $params);
$groups = $facebook->api('/me/groups', $params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook recommends using [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) for this; http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/performance
by combining your requests in a (nested) query.

Their own example:

```
$friends_locations = $facebook->api_client->fql_query(
    'SELECT hometown_location from user where uid in ' .
    '(SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1=' . $user_id . ')');
```

If your requests aren't dependant on eachother you can use [fql.multiquery](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery)

Comment: Any ideas on using the new Graph API to make an FQL query?  This looks like the older REST API...  the current Graph API-friendly PHP SDK (v2.1.2) doesn't seem to have any apparent FQL Query methods.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; the FQL is there to support requests that aren't able with the Graph API, so using the Graph API to make FQL doesn't seem to make sense?

Comment: "Facebook Query Language, or FQL, enables you to use a SQL-style interface to query the data exposed by the Graph API. It provides for some advanced features not available in the Graph API, including batching multiple queries into a single call."

Comment: You can use FQL with the current PHP SDK by specifying something like `array('method'=>'fql.query', 'query'=>$fql)` as a parameter to `$facebook->api`.

Answer (score 50):

Just an update for the new graph Batch API: You can also execute that as follows:

```
// Save your method calls into an array
$queries = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/me'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/me/groups')
);
// POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
$batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');

// Return values are indexed in order of the original array, content is in ['body'] as a JSON
// string. Decode for use as a PHP array.

$user_profile = json_decode($batchResponse[0]['body'], true);
$user_groups = json_decode($batchResponse[1]['body'], true);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks ! But be careful : "We currently limit the number of batch requests to 50." http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/

Comment: Right-- it limits the requests in the batch to 50, not a total of 50 batch requests in your app. Also, if you wanted to get creative, you could batch batch requests. You get an insanely slow response, so I've only done that in apps that have persistant auth and need an eventual response to update data. Or, a cron job. Or any massive operation really. I've never had an issue with batch limiting, and I've done some obscene things with this endpoint that would make all of you weep in disgust.

Comment: @Buzzedword I've been looking for this for the past hour, thanks!! They should put your example on the Facebook PHP SDK documentation!

Answer (score 2):

I have given example for batch calls of fql queries. It might help someone.

//$current_user=facebook id

```
 $query1="SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE is_app_user=1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $current_user)";
 $query2="SELECT uid, name, work_history FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $current_user )";
 $query3="SELECT uid, name, work, education FROM user WHERE uid = $current_user";
 $queries = array(
           array('method'=>'GET', 'relative_url'=>'method/fql.query?query='.str_replace(' ','+',$query1)),
           array('method'=>'GET', 'relative_url'=>'method/fql.query?query='.str_replace(' ','+',$query2)),
           array('method'=>'GET', 'relative_url'=>'method/fql.query?query='.str_replace(' ','+',$query3))
            );

            $objs = $facebook->api('/?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
```

$objs gets json array of whole result of thre queries.

And it is saving time a lot. This 3 queries individually takes total 9 seconds. With multiquery it takes 7 seconds. And with batch request it takes 3.6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I added a null check to mine:

```
$friends_locations = $facebook->api_client->fql_query('SELECT name,birthday_date, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT uid2 from friend where uid1='. $user_id .') and birthday_date > 0');
```

Answer (score 0):

For Batch API, you could use the [Facebook Batch PHP class](http://blog.pclabs.com.tr/gokhanozturk/2011/11/17/facebook-batch-requests-php-class/).

[Here is the code you would use](http://snipt.org/qpJp4):

```
<?php

// Facebook Batch Requests PHP Class
// by Gokhan Ozturk <gokhanozturk at gmail dot com> @ Nov 17, 2011
// Original Article: http://blog.pclabs.com.tr/gokhanozturk/2011/11/17/facebook-batch-requests-php-class/

class facebook_batch {
protected $requests = array();
protected $responses = null;
protected $cur = 1;
protected $map = array();

const MAX_NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS = 20;

public function add($path, $method = 'GET', $params = array(), $extra = array()) {
if(count($this->requests) > self::MAX_NUMBER_OF_REQUESTS) return false;

$path = trim($path, '/ ');

$body = http_build_query($params);
$body = urldecode($body);

if(strtolower($method) == 'get') {
if(count($params) > 0) {
$path .= "?" . $body;
$body = "";
}
}

$key = $this->cur++;
$this->requests[$key] = array_merge(array('relative_url' => $path, 'method' => $method, 'body' => $body), $extra);

return intval($key);
}

public function remove($key) {
unset($this->requests[$key]);
}

public function execute() {
global $facebook;

$i = 0;
foreach($this->requests as $k => $r) {
$this->map[$k] = $i++;
}

$batch = json_encode(array_values($this->requests));
$params = array('batch' => $batch);

$this->responses = $facebook->api('/', 'POST', $params);
}

public function response($key) {
if(! $this->responses) $this->execute();

$rkey = $this->map[intval($key)];
$resp = $this->responses[intval($rkey)];

if($resp['code'] != 200) return false;
return json_decode($resp['body'], true);
}

public function getRequests() {
return $this->requests;
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code, or instructions here? If the website went down, or shut down, we would have no information here.