# Batch request query

Tags: php, facebook, graph, facebook-batch-request

I am working with the batch request of the Facebook.  I have tried the api call as shown below. Is there anything wrong here?

```
[{"method":"POST","relative_url": "xxxxxxxxx/apprequests?message=hello&access_token=xxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},{"method":"GET","relative_url": "xxxxxxxx/mutualfriends/xxxxxxxxx"}]

<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Method Not Implemented</H1>
Invalid method in request<P> 
</BODY></HTML>
```

here xxxxxx is the facebook userid and access_token=xxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxx is facebook app access token.

Comment: Here's how to do it in the PHP SDK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107587/batch-calls-with-facebook-graph-api-php/7296533#7296533

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems:

1. Set the access token as a separate parameter, not included as part of the `relative_url` attribute in the JSON payload.
2. Don't include the `message` as part of the `relative_url`. Create a `body` attribute instead and pass `message=hello` as the value.

e.g.

```
curl -F 'access_token=XYZ' \
     -F 'batch=[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"xxxxxxxxx/apprequests", "body","message=hello"},{"method":"GET","relative_url": "xxxxxxxx/mutualfriends/xxxxxxxxx"}]'  'https://graph.facebook.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

The urls passed in the batch need to be urlencoded.