# How distinguish between pages and applications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using [php-sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) I obtain pages in this way:

```
$array = $this->instance->api(
    '/' . $fb_user . '/accounts', 'GET', array('access_token' => $access_token)
);
```

Now `var_dump($array['data']);` gives me:

```
array (
0 => 
array (
    'name' => 'my name 1',
    'access_token' => '***',
    'category' => 'Electronics',
    'id' => '***',
),
1 => 
array (
    'name' => 'my name 2',
    'access_token' => '***',
    'category' => 'Application',
    'id' => '***',
)
```

Only the first item is a page, the second is an app. Any way to distinguish them or improve this snippet?

EDIT: Using the `category` field seems a too weak procedure.

Comment: Can't believe this got zero upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on "category", you need to fetch informations from these ids.

Run a query for:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[page_or_app_id]
```

Among other things, there will be field:

```
{
    [...]
    "type": "application"
]
```

or:

```
{
    [...]
    "type": "page"
]
```

To avoid long responses, you may consider Batch Requests as described:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ (general instruction)
- [Batch calls with Facebook Graph API & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107587/batch-calls-with-facebook-graph-api-php) (php examples)

Answer (score 1):

Give that the category says "Application", I'd use the category property to filter with.
Alternatively, if as you say using category is too weak for you. You can use strong FQL.  `SELECT display_name FROM application WHERE app_id='{the id from your me/accounts}'` and see if you get back an object or not.

Comment: +1 I have seen a couple of tutorials that filter by category. So I will use it in that way. Thanks again DMCS.