# Using the Facebook graph API to retrieve comments for statuses in REVERSE chronological order

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve comments for statuses from Facebook's Graph API in REVERSE chronological order, that is the newest comments should be on top. I am not sure if this is even possible.

I know Facebook orders posts in chronologically descending order by default, and comments are chronologically ascending (oldest on top) by default. By default, I mean in Facebook.com and the way they are retrieved from the API.

Using the Graph API I am able to retrieve statuses in descending order, but comments are returned in ascending order. I'd like to get the comments in reverse order from the API without having to sort them in my program. The reason being is that the program is limited to the # of comments it will download, so setting the limit=xx will actually retrieve the first xx comments, rather than the newest xx comments. This is no good for me because if a status has 500 comments, and xx=100, it will always retrieve the same set of comments (first 100 to be posted).

The best parameter for the Html request that I can find is 'order_by' which looks for a time/date param (updated_time), but this does not actually work since it is already ordered by the updated_time (but ascending). I would like to specify order_by descending updated_time, if possible.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this with the API but one way to get this working is to retrieve all the comments for the status, assign them to an array, and loop through the results in reverse order.

The below example gets the last status update from the Guinness Ireland page and assigns all the messages into an array. Once we have this array we can spit out the results with a loop.

**Example:**
$data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/GuinnessIreland/statuses?limit=1&access_token=' . $ACCESS_TOKEN);

$comments = json_decode($data);
$messages = ($comments->data[0]->comments->data);

for ($counter = count($messages); $counter >= 0; $counter = $counter - 1) {
      echo $messageArray[$counter]->message;
      echo $messageArray[$counter]->created_time;
}

Comment: I'm trying to avoid manually sorting them. Do you know how to send a multiquery fql command? I try

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"query1":"SELECT id FROM comment WHERE post_id="id"}

but I keep getting: {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 601
  }
}

Comment: @TomA You can get information on batching here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/ and there is also some information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107587/batch-calls-with-facebook-graph-api-php

Comment: Thanks Neil, I just used my first idea of polling all the comments, sorting, and selecting the newest ones. This is not ideal, but Facebook's API does not seem to be as flexible as one might think.

Comment: @TomA you could try doing it with fql and order by the time desc. e.g. This example gets comments left on ebay.com and returns them in reverse order: `https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://ebay.com') ORDER BY time DESC`

Comment: I need to retrieve comments for a status based on its ID. So if my status ID is '1234567' how would I do this using FQL? Thanks

Comment: @TomA We'll get there yet! :) `SELECT id, post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time FROM comment WHERE object_id='10150928830189736' ORDER BY time DESC` where 10150928830189736 is your statusID

Answer (score 0):

You can get the comments using get request through this url.. you will get json response.

https://graph.facebook.com/"StatusID"/comments?limit=500&access_token="accessToken"

StatusID=132343454_54346345
         userID     statusid
accessToken=user Access token.

you ll get JSOn response. get all the details like user who commented, commentid, message... 
you will get JSON response . Parse them.check the comment on next page by connecting url in 
"next" string in the "page" object at the bottom of the JSON Page.
Enjoy.